# Get email address from Outlook GAL?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following code to try and grab the GAL from Outlook and drop the person's name + their email address into another sheet.

It gets the first name (but not email address) then stops. If I comment out `Sheets("Emails").Cells(intCounter, 2) = objAddressEntry.PrimarySmtpAddress`, it lists all the names succesfully, which suggests I might be using the wrong type to get the email address. VBA has no intellisense though so I'm not sure what to use instead!

```
Private Sub UpdateEmails()

' Need to add reference to Outlook
' Adds addresses to existing Sheet called Emails and
' defines name NamesAndEmailAddresses containing this list

On Error GoTo error

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objAddressList As Outlook.AddressList
Dim objAddressEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim intCounter As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Setup connection to Outlook application
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objAddressList = objOutlook.Session.AddressLists("Global Address List")

Application.EnableEvents = False

' Clear existing list
Sheets("Emails").Range("A:A").Clear

'Step through each contact and list each that has an email address
For Each objAddressEntry In objAddressList.AddressEntries
    If objAddressEntry.Address <> "" Then
        intCounter = intCounter + 1
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing no. " & intCounter & " ... " & objAddressEntry.Address
        Sheets("Emails").Cells(intCounter, 1) = objAddressEntry.Name
        Sheets("Emails").Cells(intCounter, 2) = objAddressEntry.PrimarySmtpAddress
        DoEvents
    End If
Next objAddressEntry

' Define range called "NamesAndEmailAddresses" to the list of emails
Sheets("Emails").Cells(1, 2).Resize(intCounter, 1).Name = "NamesAndEmailAddresses"
error:
Set objOutlook = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = False

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [AddressEntry Object (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/addressentry-object-outlook) page on MSDN, the property you want is `AddressEntry.Address`

```
Sheets("Emails").Cells(intCounter, 2) = objAddressEntry.Address
```

Also, if you early-bind Outlook from the **Tools** > **References...*** then you will get Intellisense.  Or, you can hit [Alt]+[F11] in Outlook and use the Intellisense there.

**{EDIT}** *Since this is giving the path on the Exchange Server rather than as a full e-mail address*
If the Contact is in an Exchange Address List, then you can use `.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress` to get the Primary Smtp Address for the user on the Exchange Server.  (For local contacts on your account, use the `GetContact.Email1Address` instead)

```
Sheets("Emails").Cells(intCounter, 2) = objAddressEntry.GetExchangeuser.PrimarySmtpAddress
```

Comment: I already tried `Address` but it's bringing back results like this: `/o=domain/ou=First Administrative Group/cn=Recipients/cn=name` rather than email addresses

Comment: @MrJF Since that is just bringing back the Exchange User rather than the full domain path, you can use `.GetExchangeUser`.  Sometimes you get something like "smtp:forename.surname@domain.com" from `.Address` instead, depending on how it's set up.  Answer updated

Comment: Sorry - that hasnt worked either. When i used `.GetExchangeUser` it stopped the code from running again like when I had the smtp address thing earlier.

Answer (score -1):

To obtain or check if a person has an email address on the GAL:
(see this [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser))

```
Sub testGetEmail()
Debug.Print GetEmailName("Dupont", "Alain")
End Sub

Function GetEmailName(FirstName As String, SecondName As String) As String
Dim oExUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
Dim oAL As Outlook.AddressList

    Set oAL = Application.Session.AddressLists.Item(["Global Address List"])
    FullName = FirstName & ", " & SecondName
    Set oExUser = oAL.AddressEntries.Item([FullName]).GetExchangeUser
    GetEmailName = oExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
End Function
```